# proper phpdoc @return for factory method

Tags: php, phpdoc

I am curious how to document the following scenario. Imagine a group of classes:

```
abstract class Personality {}
class Me extends Personality {}
class Myself extends Personality {}
class Irene extends Personality {}
```

If I am writing a factory-esque method to instantiate and return a subclass of class Personality, how would I properly document the @return?

```
@return mixed  A "Personality" subclass object
```

or

```
@return Personality  A "Personality" subclass object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@return Personality A "Personality" subclass object
```

is the best. And IDE will provide you with autocomplete properties for the Personality class.

Comment: Is there no way to specify that a factory method returns an instance of the class on which the factory method is called? (E.g. `Irene::create()`)

Comment: @crishoj There is: `@return static`. This isn't in the PhpDocumentor documentation, but is supported by PhpStorm, NetBeans and probably other editors.